# FFmpeg mp4 to m3u8 but audio not working

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, m3u8, hls.js

Command I'm using

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset superfast -r 25 -vb 240000 -s 
426x240 -aspect 1.77 -acodec libfdk_aac -ab 128k -ar 48000 -an -g 30 -r 30 
-hls_time 3 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_allow_cache 1 -hls_playlist_type vod 
-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc video.m3u8
```

output shows "no audio"

http://dailymotion.github.io/hls.js/demo/?src=http%3A%2F%2Ftvfiless.com%2Fvideo.m3u8&enableStreaming=true&autoRecoverError=true&enableWorker=true&levelCapping=-1

anyone help what's wrong in my command

**Update**

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 output.m3u8`

i tried this command and its working fine, generating audio with m3u8, but i want to integrate it with my above command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -y -i video1.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset superfast -r 25 -vb 240000 -s 426x240 -aspect 1.77 -acodec libfdk_aac -ab 128k -ar 48000 -f hls -hls_time 3 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_allow_cache 1 -hls_playlist_type vod output.m3u8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove

> -an

from the cli, it means discard audio in generating output in ffmpeg.

Comment: After remove -an  it returns error  "[mpegts @ 0x3800620] AAC bitstream not in ADTS format and extradata missing"